# Building a countdown timer using C# in Razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

is it possible to use Razor syntax to build a countdown timer in Pages (asp .net core 3.1) project.
if yes, please share the steps and code snippets. I am trying to use c# only with razor view  (@ {} )  only. sometime like this.

```
 @{
string message = "";
Timer timer;
void TickTimer(Object sender)
{
    // do something 
  
}

timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(TickTimer), null, 1000, 1000);
```

}

Answer (score 9):

It can be implemented in blazor：

```
@using System.Threading;

<h1>@Count</h1>

<button @onclick=@StartCountdown>Start Timer</button>

@functions {
    private int Count { get; set; } = 10;

    void StartCountdown()
    {
        var timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(_ =>
        {
            if (Count > 0)
            {
                Count--;

            InvokeAsync(() =>
                {

                    StateHasChanged();
                });
            }
        }), null, 1000, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: `@code {...}` is used nowadays. `StartCountdown` can be implemented in the `OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)` lifecycle method.